# Are "nil" and "null" interchangeable?

Tags: differences, word-usage

Are *nil* and *null* interchangeable? For example,

> My bank a/c has a **nil** balance.
>
> My bank a/c has a **null** balance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a real difference between "null" and "zero"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/is-there-a-real-difference-between-null-and-zero) (as implied in the top answer there, *nil* equates to *zero*)

Comment: What does "a/c" stand for in this context? Obviously not "air conditioning"...

Comment: @Marthaª, a/c-->account

Comment: @VijinPaulraj: really? Then why the slash? IME a slash is used in abbreviations to indicate separate words; it seems... misleading to use it between the first two letters of a word.

Comment: yes..i think it's an explicit abbr., because air conditioner always mention as A/C(capitalized).Look up [here](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=a%2Fc)

Comment: @Marthaª: Not necessarily separate words; *D/C*, for example, means "discharge" or "discontinue", and *w/o* means "without" (cf. *w/* "with"). But I agree, *a/c* is surprising.

Comment: One must be careful with these terms in any sort of mathematical, computer programming, or physics context, as they tend to have specialized meanings.

Comment: @ruakh the separation makes sense since those are prefixes attached to the noun; not the case in "a"/"ccount"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English

Comment: There are BrE/AmE differences here as well.  A British sports reporter would report a football score as "nil-nil" when an American would say "zero to zero".

Comment: [Master](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2kb4p9r0) distinguishes the null article ('He was elected king' = 'He was elected Ø2 king', most definite) from the zero article ('We're having chicken for dinner' = 'We're having Ø1 chicken for dinner', most indefinite).

Answer (score 17):

NULL is used in computing most often (always?) to signify "not a value." This is different than zero: in a bank database, a zero value means no money, while a NULL value means there has been no value assigned to the balance.

This is a specialized usage, but increasingly common as more people learn to program.

Comment: I use the word *null* just about daily in computer programming. It is extremely common for anyone creating software.

Comment: You forgot to add that 'null' and 'nil' are identical in programming; exact usage simply depends on which one a language has chosen to standardize on.

Comment: If you're writing in C, NULL is interchangeable with the value 0, though this isn't recommended

Comment: @dreadiscool it's not in general interchangeable. A conformant implementation may define it as `((void*)0)` (which many do), which you then can't use in e.g. arithmetic: `5*NULL` will give you a compilation error.

Answer (score 12):

Almost the only time you hear or see *null* is in the legal expression ‘null and void’, while *nil* normally indicates that a football team has scored no goals. If  the bottom line of your bank statement shows neither a credit nor a debit, what you have is a *zero balance*.

Comment: i dunno about other countries. But in India, here banks provide a special a/c i.e, no-frills a/c. and that is often called as null balance a/c, nil balance a/c, zero balance a/c.

Comment: As a side note, _nil_ is rarely used in the U.S. for sports scores; _nothing_ is used far more often (or, in place of _nothing_, one might hear _zero_, or even _zip_).  The one exception I hear is when ardent soccer fans are discussing a soccer match ("Spain beat Portugal 2-0," [pronounced "two-nil"]; but, "The Falcons beat the Seahawks 10-0," [pronounced "ten-nothing"]).  As a side note to my side note, _very_ ardent soccer fans will refer to soccer as "_real_ football." :^)

Comment: A good example then, @Vijin, of Indian English, but I don't quite understand how a bank can offer a zero balance account. The whole point of a bank account, surely, is either to have a plus or a minus balance.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_no_frills_account  the above mentioned a/c is called nil,null,zero balance a/c

Answer (score 12):

Nil means zero or nought

Null means nothing or empty

In everyday life, we tend to treat these terms as equivalent. But it is sometimes important to differentiate between them. (E.g. when working with SQL database data)

Answer (score 11):

*Null* is also used in mathematics (a null set) and science (null hypothesis). I can't think of a time when *nil* is used in those areas.

Etymologically, null is from French, and nil is from Latin.

Comment: *[Nilpotent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nilpotent)* is a common term, usually written as one word and sometimes as two, *nil potent*.  Per [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nil+potent%2Cnil+-+potent&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *nil potent,nil - potent* it appears all or nearly all of the hyphenated instances (like "nil- potent") result from end-of-line hyphenation.

Comment: But Ruby and Lua, even Golang uses `nil` instead of `null`.

Comment: @JLG  I wonder then from where does 'null' come in French...

Answer (score 6):

Null is also used in physics and electronics. Here's a [description of a Null comparator](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3az27A4tek2CEJ%3awww.physics.fsu.edu/courses/fall98/phy2049c/labs/L5/lab5.pdf%20%22null%20comparator%22&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShz6CZ4vR6LJiBSO0kQDw5iS5fTpQaMg49JHk8jf7cvg49Et9gAssckDHqy6nfBj4_zywUfQuafgENCgJ4PmKixsEJCF3Ua5F6kA2KJx66981APOaEJ1MjiQKqqTewSA2g6Vs75&sig=AHIEtbTX7SSEsab8c_aPAAUrFgvyyBouZQ) using a Wheatstone bridge.
Null tends to describe something with no net value, but possibly the sum of large values of opposing signs, while nil implies a value of 0.

Answer (score -1):

Nil means no less than or greater than 0 and null means no value in variable or any storage media

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).