# Is there a word to describe content as not having a duration, as opposed to something for playback?

Tags: single-word-requests

Just as the word **empty** is saying that something is *of volume zero* I wonder if there is a word that says that something is *of length zero* or has *a duration of zero*.

Sample Sentence:

> The program should terminate if the calculated period is
>   _______.

Comment: I'd use "instantaneous", for zero duration.

Comment: You could re-work your sentence to read: "The program should terminate if the calculated period evaluates to zero.", replacing *is* with *evaluates to*.

Comment: What's wrong with saying that the period is *zero* if that's what the *calculation* yielded?

Comment: I am not sure that the recent edit has really improved the question. The reference to playback implies that what is sought is a technical term that is to be used in some highly specific context; the original version of the question was much more general. The question should be reopened anyway.

Comment: "Empty" doesn't mean "volume zero."

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can just use *zero* in this particular case. The beauty of zero is that units don't matter; zero seconds is the same as zero years.

A related word is *instantaneous*:

> done, occurring, or acting without any perceptible duration of time

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instantaneous))</sub>

but you wouldn't use it in this sample sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"*O-length*" and "*zero-length*" are profusely used in mathematics and physics textbooks, which would suggest that a better word is still to be found. Sorry.

P.S.: The term "*null*" is quite popular but I'm not sure that it has a legitimate place in non-tech literature.

Comment: See this question regarding whether zero and null perfect synonyms: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/is-there-a-real-difference-between-null-and-zero

Comment: Personally I don't think they are but a thorough discussion would bring us deep into mathematical philosophy. The doubt is rather whether "_null_" (in English) is an accepted word in non-geek talk.

Answer (score 0):

*Zero* works as already pointed out. If you want to avoid it for some reason, you can use ***nil***. A lesser used synonym is ***zilch***.

> The program should terminate if the calculated period is ***nil***.

M-W:

> **[nil](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nil)**
> *noun*
>
> :  nothing, zero
>
> They took a 2 to nil lead in the second half of the game.
>
> **[zilch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zilch)** *adjective or noun*
>
> :  zero, nothing

Comment: The OP’s sample sentence seems to be fairly formal; e.g., it could come from a system specification or requirements document.   The word “nil” strikes me as informal; “zilch” even more so.   P.S. I am American; are these words considered more formal in Br.E?

Answer (score -2):

There is word that fits your definition, although it doesn't fit your example sentence.

***[Infinitesimal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/infinitesimal?s=t)***

> adjective
>
> 1. indefinitely or exceedingly small; minute:
>      infinitesimal vessels in the circulatory system.
> 2. immeasurably small; less than an assignable quantity:
>      to an infinitesimal degree.
> 3. of, relating to, or involving infinitesimals.
>
> noun
>
> 4. an infinitesimal quantity.
> 5. Mathematics. a variable having zero as a limit.