# Word for an event with no duration?

Tags: single-word-requests, time

I need to use two words to distinguish between two types of events (or timeblocks in a timeline).

- Some of them have a duration: e.g.: *From 20:00 to 21:00 is a **{word1}***
- Some of them have no duration: e.g.: *The 3rd of March is a **{word2}***

Are there some English words that would express this difference?

I thought to use *discrete event* for **word2**, but it seems a bit clumsy. And what about **word1** in that case?

Comment: [Related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/372106/116151).

Comment: 1-a period of time. 2-a point of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd of March *is* an event with a duration, of 24 hours to be precise. *Noon* would be an event which has no duration, and can be said to be an *instant*:

> an infinitesimal space of time

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instant))</sub>

For the other kind of event, *time span* or *period* might work, but I'm sure there are better alternatives.

If you need adjectives to distinguish between the two types of events, *instantaneous* and *non-instantaneous* would work.

Comment: a span of time or space; a point in time or space

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Glorfindel's clarification, your second example does have a duration. I will also provide an answer to the question in the title: a word for an event with no duration.

An event with no (or sufficiently small) duration is sometimes referred to as a **split second**. According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/split-second):

> a very short moment of time

Their example sentences:

> They brought out guns and for a **split second** nobody moved.
>
> We had to make a **split-second** (= very quick) decision.

Attribution: (Definition of “split second” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)